# Outlook run macro when mail arrives on a nondefault mailbox

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have multiple mailboxes set-up in my Outlook 2010. I would like a macro to run when I receive a mail on one of the non-default mailboxes.

I have coded the below and inserted the code into **`"ThisOutlookSession"`**.

I have gotten it to work for the default mailbox's inbox but not my nondefault mailbox's inbox. When I try to re-open outlook 2010 having inserted the code, It tells me :
`"Compile error in hidden module: ThisOutlookSession".` The non-default box is called 'abc.asia'.

I am new to vba so any inputs are appreciated, thank you!

```
Dim WithEvents myInboxMailItem As Outlook Items

Private Sub myInboxMailItem_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    MsgBox("Item Added")
End Sub

Private Sub Initialize_Handler()
    Dim fldInbox As Outlook.MapiFolder
    Dim gnspNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set gnspNameSpace = Outlook.GetNameSpace("Mapi")
    Set fldInbox = gnspNameSpace.Folders("abc.asia").Folders("Inbox")
    Set myInboxMailtItem = fldInbox.Items

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `Set olRecip = olNs.CreateRecipient("emal@address.com")` with correct Email address.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olRecip As Recipient

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olRecip = olNs.CreateRecipient("emal@address.com")  '// Owner's Name or email address
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Debug.Print Item.Subject
    End If
End Sub
```