# How to move mail from shared mailbox to a subfolder based on calculated entries in Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, excel-2007, outlook-2007

I export e-mail details from an Outlook 2007 shared inbox folder into an Excel 2007 sheet (Sender, Subject, Date & time received).

I then use formulas in Excel 2007 to attempt to extract a reference from the subject. Then lookup the reference against some data exported from our computer system.

- If the reference matches with a file reference then set criteria from a formula will populate an answer in column D (so that's Sender, Subject, Date & time received, Yes/No).
- If the reference can't be found or the data from the file doesn't meet the criteria to merit a response column D will then show "Yes" (meaning it needs to be marked as read and moved to the folder "No Response" which is part of the same shared mailbox on the same level as the inbox) otherwise will show "No" (in which case nothing needs to be done to that e-mail). The Yes/No Column formula criteria will be a continuous work in progress.

Exporting the e-mail details into an Excel sheet works and so do all of the formulas.

I've not managed to get Outlook to take the appropriate action from the details in the Excel sheet.

```vb
Sub ExportToExcel()
    
    ' Fully working, will export Sender, Subject & Date Received from e-mails into spreadsheet *** Except For Non-Mail Items ***
    ' If getting "spreadsheet user-defined type not defined" go to Visual Basic > Tools > References and tick 'Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library'
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim strSheet As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim intRowCounter As Integer
    Dim intColumnCounter As Integer
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim nms As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim fld As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim itm As Object
    
    'Set path for spreadsheet
    strSheet = "OE.xlsx"
    strPath = "C:\Users\JM\Desktop\"
    strSheet = strPath & strSheet
    Debug.Print strSheet
    
    'Select export folder
    Set nms = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fld = nms.PickFolder
        
    'Handle potential errors with Select Folder dialog box.
    If fld Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There are no mail messages to export", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Exit Sub
    
    ElseIf fld.DefaultItemType <> olMailItem Then
        MsgBox "There are no mail messages to export", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Exit Sub
    
    ElseIf fld.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no mail messages to export", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Exit Sub
    
    End If
    
    'Open and activate Excel workbook.
    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appExcel.Workbooks.Open (strSheet)
    Set wkb = appExcel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
    wks.Activate
    appExcel.Application.Visible = True
       
    'Copy field items in mail folder.
    For Each itm In fld.Items
        intColumnCounter = 1
        Set msg = itm
        intRowCounter = intRowCounter + 1
        Set rng = wks.Cells(intRowCounter, intColumnCounter)
        intColumnCounter = intColumnCounter
        Set rng = wks.Cells(intRowCounter, intColumnCounter)
        'rng.Value = msg.SenderEmailAddress
        rng.Value = msg.SenderEmailAddress
        intColumnCounter = intColumnCounter + 1
        Set rng = wks.Cells(intRowCounter, intColumnCounter)
        rng.Value = msg.Subject
        intColumnCounter = intColumnCounter
        intColumnCounter = intColumnCounter + 1
        Set rng = wks.Cells(intRowCounter, intColumnCounter)
        rng.Value = msg.ReceivedTime
    Next itm
                
    MsgBox "Export Complete", vbOKOnly, "Information"
    Set appExcel = Nothing
    Set wkb = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set msg = Nothing
    Set nms = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set itm = Nothing
    Exit Sub
    
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox strSheet & " doesn't exist", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Else
    End If
    Set appExcel = Nothing
    Set wkb = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set msg = Nothing
    Set nms = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set itm = Nothing
    MsgBox "Export Completed", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

This is what the spreadsheet would look like, I can't show the original because of data protection.
[image]

Most of the code has been put together from a few different websites.

The predominant source of the code was this site
http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?52247-Macro-to-send-out-email-based-on-criteria-via-outlook/page3&s=11b5bf88fb5e89d06f7c8b43f6f92d2e

I want the following code to:

- Mark the "Yes" e-mails as read and move them into the shared "No Response" folder in Outlook (in the same shared mailbox as the inbox the e-mail details were exported from).

This is where I am so far. The code will recognise an e-mail, mark it as unread, flag it as complete but it won't move the items into the folder or process the whole folder.

```vb
Option Explicit
Const strWorkbook As String = "C:\Users\jmurrey\Desktop\OE.xlsm" 'The path of the workbook
Const strSheet As String = "Sheet1" 'The name of the worksheet
Sub ProcessFolder()
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim olFolder As Folder
    Set olFolder = Session.PickFolder 'select the folder
    For Each olItem In olFolder.Items 'loop through the items
        If TypeName(olItem) = "MailItem" Then
            MoveToFolder olItem 'run the macro
        End If
        Exit For
    Next olItem
    Set olItem = Nothing
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub MailFilter()
    Dim olMsg As MailItem
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olMsg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    MoveToFolder olMsg
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
     
Sub MoveToFolder(olMail As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olReply As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim oRng As Object
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim iCols As Long
    Dim iRows As Long
    Dim strName As String
    'load the worksheet into an array
    Arr = xlFillArray(strWorkbook, strSheet)
    With olMail
        For iRows = 0 To UBound(Arr, 2) 'Check each row of the array
            'If column 2 (starting at column 0) contains the e-mail address of the message
            If .SenderEmailAddress = Arr(0, iRows) Then
                'If the subject value is in the message subject
                If InStr(1, .Subject, Arr(1, iRows)) > 0 Then
                    If InStr(1, .ReceivedTime, Arr(2, iRows)) > 0 Then
                    'If the received time is in the message subject
                        If InStr(1, "Yes", Arr(3, iRows)) > 0 Then
                        'If The string above matches then mark the email as unread and move to 'No Response' folder
                            'MsgBox "Match Found", vbOKOnly, "Match"
                            .FlagStatus = olFlagComplete
                            .UnRead = False
                            .Save
                            .Move Application.Session.Folders("No Response")
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next iRows
    End With
lbl_Exit:
    Set olReply = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub
     
Private Function xlFillArray(strWorkbook As String, _
    strWorksheetName As String) As Variant
    Dim RS As Object
    Dim CN As Object
    Dim iRows As Long
         
    strWorksheetName = strWorksheetName & "$]"
    Set CN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    CN.Open ConnectionString:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
      "Data Source=" & strWorkbook & ";" & _
      "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
         
    Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    RS.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & strWorksheetName, CN, 2, 1
         
    With RS
        .MoveLast
        iRows = .RecordCount
        .MoveFirst
    End With
    xlFillArray = RS.GetRows(iRows)
    If RS.State = 1 Then RS.Close
        Set RS = Nothing
        If CN.State = 1 Then CN.Close
        Set CN = Nothing
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

How do I move e-mails to the folder "No Response" which is in the same shared mailbox as the inbox the data has been exported from and also run through all of the e-mails in the Excel sheet rather than just one.

Comment: Where are you at exactly? **What are you stuck on? Do you get errors? Where?** Please edit your question to include those answers! ;) *Also (just bitching), why so much spacing and no indenting in your first code??*

Comment: Sorted out the spacing, I use the spacing to help read through and understand how it's working, forgot to go back to it.
Also updated the question itself

Comment: Can you add an image of your data on sheet1?

Comment: @0m3r I've added an outline of what the spreadsheet would look like and the data it would contain, note that the yes/no column is generated by a formula which isn't that relevant as up to that point it works fine.

Comment: Is it really necessary to load the worksheet for every email?  This seems very inefficient. The text of your reply suggests all you want to know is: (1) how to mark an email as read and (2) move it to another folder.  (1) Search for " outlook mailitem unread".  (2) Search for " outlook mailitem move".

Comment: Yes its is,effectively the purpose of it is to cull hundreds of e-mails. The first script pulls the e-mails out, then I receive a load of case data that I put into the spreadsheet, I put a formula in that strips a reference from the subject if it's there, then the Yes/No column is a vlookup of the reference against the system data. Then from that point the second script I was trying to get it to move the e-mails and mark them read. It's not a problem to do that manually until you get towards triple digits  but when there's upwards of 700 e-mails this saves loads of time.

Comment: I've tried .move and it for some reason doesn't seem to work in the context of the script, I must be placing it in the wrong place.

MSDN suggests it should be used as ``` myItem.Move myDestFolder ```
you can see above that I've tried tot use ``` .Move Session.Folders("No Response") ```

I'm not experienced enough with outlook code to troubleshoot the issue so I thought I'd ask for help :)

Comment: Might be worth recording the `EntryID` for each email - this is the unique email ID that a store (folder) assigns to an email when it is added to that store... note, moving the email to a different folder will change the `EntryID`.  I'm pretty sure you can search for emails in VBA using it.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211865(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: I'm at the point now where the script works to mark the e-mail as read or `.UnRead = False` but I can't get my head around quite how to get .move to work, I've tried quite a different permutations, I think ultimately it's down to referencing the "No Response" folder that's the issue.

Comment: on outlook vba it should be  `.Move Application.Session.Folders("No Response")`

Comment: Has it worked for you?

Comment: Sorry, just back from lunch. The code marks it unread, sets the flag but doesn't move the mail item

Answer (score 2):

I have many issues with your code.  With some issues, I am sure your code is faulty.  With other issues I am not so sure.  I will work down your code discussing my issues which I hope will help you address your problem.

Don’t use `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` during development or after release if you can avoid it.  Your code will report the non-existence of the workbook but in the event of any other error it will just stop without giving no indication that it has failed to complete its task or the reason.

Try this for the workbook problem and add code for any other problems as they are discovered:

```
  Set wkb = Nothing
  On Error Resume Next
  Set wkb = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(strSheet)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If wkb Is Nothing Then
    Call MsgBox("I cannot open the workbook", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If
```

`Dim intRowCounter As Integer`.  We were told to stop using data type `Integer` with VBA because it declares a 16-bit variable and such variables required special – slow - processing on 32 and 64-bit computers.  When I got around to testing this claim, I was unable to detect any difference in processing speed.  My reason for not using `Integer` for a row number is that its maximum value is 32767.  I assume you will not have that many emails per folder but I will still suggest you get into the habit of declaring row numbers as `Long`.

You do not initialise `intRowCounter`.  The default value is 0 and you add 1 before first use so it starts as 1.

`strSheet = "OE.xlsx"`.  Not very important but I hate anything that might cause confusion in the future. "OE.xlsx" is the name of a workbook and not the name of a worksheet.  The term “spreadsheet” dates back to when there was only one sheet per file and I consider it obsolete.

You use `PickFolder` to select the folder which is fine if you want to be able run this macro against multiple folders.  I was concerned you were using `PickFolder` because you did not know how else to get a folder reference particularly as you are using Explorer in `MailFilter()`.

Alternatively, since you are playing with Explorer, perhaps this technique will appeal.  The user selects the target folder and then starts your macro with this code at the beginning:

```
  Dim Exp As Outlook.Explorer
  Dim Fldr As Folder

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("No emails selected", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  Else
    Set Fldr = Exp.Selection(1).Parent
  End If
```

`Exp.Selection(1)` is the first or only selected email.

`Exp.Selection(1).Parent` is the folder containing the selected email.

There is no need to activate the worksheet.

I would never identify columns by number unless the nature of the task required it.  I would replace your code by:

```
Const ColEmSenderEmailAddress As Long = 1
Const ColEmSubject As Long = 2
Const ColEmReceivedTime As Long = 3

wks.Cells(intRowCounter, ColEmSenderEmailAddress).Value = msg.SenderEmailAddress
wks.Cells(intRowCounter, ColEmSubject).Value = msg.Subject
wks.Cells(intRowCounter, ColEmReceivedTime).Value = msg.ReceivedTime
```

I think this is easier to read and, more importantly, if any of the columns move, you only need to update the constants.

In your first macro you use `For Each itm In fld.Items` to access the mail items.  In the second you use Explorer to access the first or only selected email.  You must be consistent.

I rarely use `For Each itm In fld.Items` and have never experimented with the sequence in which items are presented to the macro.  In the second macro, you will be removed items from the folder by moving them elsewhere.  Again I have never experimented so do not know how this might affect the items returned by `For Each itm In fld.Items`.  I doubt there will be an effect but you will need to check if you want to use `For Each itm In fld.Items` in both macros.

I would use something like this for the first macro:

```
  Dim InxMi As Long
  Dim itm As MailItem

  For InxMi = 1 To Fldr.Items.Count
    Set itm = Fldr.Items(InxMi)
    Output macro to worksheet
  Next
```

Since you start at row 1 in the worksheet, this would mean the item number `InxMi` and the row number `intRowCounter` would be the same make matching rows and mail items in the second macro easier.  If there is no change to the folder between creating the worksheet and running the second macro, there will be an exact match.  If you allow additions and deletion between the two macros, it will be more complicated but rows and the mail items will be in the same sequence so not too complicated.

In the second macro, you need to start at the bottom row of the worksheet and read the folder up from the bottom:

```
  For InxMi = Fldr.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set itm = Fldr.Items(InxMi)
    If appropriate Move item
  Next
```

Mail items within a folder are like rows within worksheets, if you delete one then all the one below move up.  If you move up the worksheet and the folder, the row and mail items will continue to match because the moved mail items will below the current position.

You do not give enough detail for me to be more specific but I hope the above helps you progress.

Comment: Hi Tony, I appreciate you taking the time to help, I understand the text but, quite clearly I'm not proficient in outlook VB as I just can't get my head around the changes I need to make in order to get it working, placement of the suggested code especially. If I was going to continue to use Outlook VB regularly I'd jump in and learn more but once I've got this code up and running I won't need to use Outlook VBA.. My spare time's taken up learning android development.

Comment: @JohnMurrey. You say you collected code from different websites but I do not understand why you have not made it consistent. I am reluctant to advise further because I fear I am missing something significant.

Comment: @JohnMurrey.   In macro "ExportToExcel" you use `PickFolder` so the source Outlook folder could be ANY MailItem folder on your system. Do you need this flexibility? You open an existing workbook and start writing to row 1 of the first sheet. You do not delete any existing content nor add below existing content. Unless the source folder contains more mail items than were recorded last time, you will have a mixture of new and old mail items.  If you need to record emails from any folder, why don't you record the name of the source folder?

Comment: @JohnMurrey.   Macro "MailFilter" calls macro "MoveToFolder" to process one user selected email.  Macro "MoveToFolder" calls macro "xlFillArray" to open the workbook and read Sheet1 (which is not necessarily the first sheet) one row at a time.  It then looks down Sheet1 for the selected email and if found checks for "Yes" against it.  Why?  I would read Sheet 1 in one go, scan for each email marked "Yes" and and then locate and move that email.

Comment: Hi Tony, No I'm using `PickFolder` as this will effectively run on a shared folder and I didn't know how to specify the folder. I'll be importing the e-mails into the same spreadsheet (on sheet 1) every time with all previous e-mail records cleared from the sheet. Frankly I don't know how to record the name of the source folder. OK so, the e-mail subject goes through several formulas to find a reference, then is looked up (vlookup) against data from another system, the yes/no field is a formula to see if we need to respond based on the data from the other sheet. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @JohnMurrey  I do not had access to a shared folder but my recollection is that they are accessed in the same way as any local folder.  See [Introduction Part 3: Stores and all their folders](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/outlook-vba/8874/introduction-part-3-stores-and-all-their-folders#t=201703071500404701433).  Part 3.1 contains a function that returns the name of a folder as an array. In later parts, I use `Join` to convert an array to a string for easy display.  Part 3.3 shows how to reference and display the name of any accessible store.  Try this technique on your shared folder.

Comment: @JohnMurrey  You do not explain why the second part of your routine works as it does. You get the user to select an email then open the workbook to see if it is present and marked "Yes".  To me, the obvious approach would be to open the workbook and scan down for emails marked "Yes". Is there some significance to your chosen approach that I am missing?

Comment: OK, Tony I'll have a look. In retrospect I agree, looking for the 'Yes' rows and working back through the e-mail details would definitely save time, the main reason I haven't done that is that outlook VB is something I'm not familiar with and for me isn't as easy to learn as Excel VBA. I got the code from this forum with the intent of manipulating it to work for my purposes. the web address I got it from is: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?52247-Macro-to-send-out-email-based-on-criteria-via-outlook/page2

Comment: Hi again Tony, I've had a look at your post, I read up on recursion, interesting stuff, in my mind VLOOKUP in excel would be a good example, I've now confirmed the structure of the folders in order to reference the "No Response" folder, it's a child only to the mailbox it's in alongside the inbox, the rest of the code works for a single mail item to mark it as unread now but I'm struggling to understand how to use `. move` and reference the "No Response" folder.

Answer (score 1):

Hey why not run it from your Excel file and keep it simple -

Basic Example

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim App As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Item As Object

    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Dim RevdTime As String
    Dim Subject As String
    Dim Email As String

    Set App = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = App.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) ' Inbox
    Set Items = Inbox.Items

    iRow = 1 ' Row Count
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Update with Correct Sheet Name

        Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(iRow, 4))
            DoEvents

            If Cells(iRow, 4).Value = "Yes" Then
                RevdTime = .Cells(iRow, 3).Value ' Email ReceivedTime
                Subject = .Cells(iRow, 2).Value ' Email Subject
                Email = .Cells(iRow, 1).Value ' Email Sender Name

                For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
                    Set Item = Items(i)

                    If Item.Class = olMail And _
                       Item.Subject = Subject And _
                       Item.ReceivedTime = RevdTime And _
                       Item.SenderEmailAddress = Email Then

                       Debug.Print Item.Subject ' Immediate Window
                       Debug.Print Item.ReceivedTime ' Immediate Window
                       Debug.Print Item.SenderEmailAddress ' Immediate Window

                       Item.UnRead = False
                       Item.Save
                       Item.Move olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) _
                                              .Folders("No Response")
                    End If

                Next
            End If
            iRow = iRow + 1 ' Go to Next Row
        Loop
    End With

    Set App = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing

End Sub
```

**for Late Binding see**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim App As Object ' Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Object ' Outlook.Namespace
    Dim Inbox  As Object ' Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Object ' Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Object ' Outlook.Items
    Dim Item As Object

    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Dim RevdTime As String
    Dim Subject As String
    Dim Email As String

    Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = App.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6) '  olFolderInbox = 6
    Set Items = Inbox.Items

    iRow = 1 ' Row Count
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Update with Correct Sheet Name

        Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(iRow, 4))
            DoEvents

            If Cells(iRow, 4).Value = "Yes" Then
                RevdTime = .Cells(iRow, 3).Value ' Email ReceivedTime
                Subject = .Cells(iRow, 2).Value ' Email Subject
                Email = .Cells(iRow, 1).Value ' Email Sender Name

                For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
                    Set Item = Items(i)

                    ' olMail - 43 = A MailItem object.
                    If Item.Class = 43 And _
                       Item.Subject = Subject And _
                       Item.ReceivedTime = RevdTime And _
                       Item.SenderEmailAddress = Email Then

                       Debug.Print Item.Subject ' Immediate Window
                       Debug.Print Item.ReceivedTime ' Immediate Window
                       Debug.Print Item.SenderEmailAddress ' Immediate Window

                       Item.UnRead = False
                       Item.Save
                       Item.Move olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6) _
                                        .Folders("No Response")
                    End If

                Next
            End If
            iRow = iRow + 1 ' Go to Next Row
        Loop
    End With

    Set App = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you want to run it from Outlook let me know it shouldn't be hard-

Comment: I'll give this a go, the other answer below I understand the text but, quite clearly I'm not proficient in outlook VB as I just can't get my head around the changes I need to make in order to get it working, placement of the suggested code especially. If I was going to continue to use Outlook VB regularly I'd jump in and learn more but once I've got this code up and running I won't need to use Outlook VBA.. My spare time's taken up learning android development.

Comment: OK, I've tried the above code and it fails when it gets to the 'No Response Folder. The mailbox I'm trying to run this on is a shared mailbox not the main mailbox I use, also it's not a folder inside the Inbox of that mailbox it's on the same level as Sent Items and Inbox, not quite sure how this affects the code, could definitely use some advice please

Comment: @JohnMurrey See revised Code, run it on your inbox first - test it - once you got it working let me know then I will show you how to run it on share Inbox

Comment: I've just tried the code on my inbox and it doesn't recognize    Outlook.Application    yet both Outlook 12.0 and Excel 12.0 are ticked in VBA references

Comment: @JohnMurrey see the Late Binding code, that does not require Outlook references-

Comment: @JohnMurrey for share Inbox see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39459407/4539709

Comment: This hasn't worked on my inbox, it gets to `Item.Move olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6) _
                                        .Folders("No Response")` and can't find the object (which I'm assuming is the folder as the mail item is still in my inbox. The folder 'No Response is at the same level as my inbox (not a sub folder), I did try this`Item.Move olNs..Folders("No Response")`.  if that makes a difference, also using office 2007 (not through choice)

Comment: @JohnMurrey Okay I didn't know you ware on 2007- Try this, Change this `Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6)` to this `Set CaseFolders = Outlook.Session.Folders("0m3r@email.com").Folders("Inbox")`

Comment: OK, I've tried that and it errored as CaseFolders wasn't declared, so I declared it and set it to nothing at the end of the script and I got an error "The operation failed. An object could not be found. I replaced the e-mail with the correct one for that shared mailbox. The outlook VBA is now at a point where it will mark the e-mail as unread, but I just can't figure out what the right code is to use to move the mail item to the folder. I thik for the sake of time it would be easier to finish the Outlook code rather than keep iterating the Excel VBA to a point where it will work. Thanks :)

Comment: @JohnMurrey sorry it was supposed to be `Set Inbox = Outlook.Session.Folders("correct email address here").Folders("Inbox")` now on the Item.Move do the same

Comment: `Item.Move Outlook.Session.Folders("correct email address here").Folders("Inbox").Folders("No Response")`

Comment: OK, I've done that and I still get the same error, am I supposed to be trying this with my inbox or the shared inbox it's intended for? the e-mail I'm using in the code is not my e-mail.

Comment: Share inbox- make sure your subfolder name is correct- no response ?

Comment: I was testing it on the share inbox, the folder is called No Response. to be as clear as I can be No Response is not a child of the Inbox it's on the same level meaning that it's a child of the same mailbox as the inbox. I get the feeling that might be the issue??

Comment: How about this-      Item.Move Outlook.Session.Folders("correct email address here").Folders("No Response")

Comment: Or Item.Move Outlook.Session.Folders("No Response")

Comment: Nope, it doesn't get that far, it gets to `Outlook.Session.Folders("correct email address here").Folders("Inbox")`. I still get the error `The operation failed. An object could not be found.` I've checked the smtp address on a mail item in that mailbox so I'm definitely using the correct address. I have tried both of the above.

Comment: can you share an image of your outlook folders view? you can hide all the personal staff

Comment: Okay it Should be `Set Inbox = olNs.Session.Folders("Mailbox - John Murrey").Folders("Inbox")` make sure to replace `John Murrey` with the correct name of the mailbox

Comment: And `Item.Move olNs.Session.Folders("Mailbox - John Murrey").Folders("No Response")` make sure to replace John Murrey with the correct name of the mailbox

Comment: I've tried that with both bits altered and entered the mailbox name as it shows in outlook, still the same error. I've got the outlook VBA code to a point where it will set a flag on one e-mail at a time. just trying to get it to get it to run through them all but still building the array once.

Answer (score 1):

I did not know where to start with fixing your code so I have started from scratch based on my best guesses regarding your requirement.

I created a file named OE.xlsx with a single worksheet named “Emails” since I avoid using the default worksheet names.  I created a header line with values: “Sender”, “Subject”, “Received”, “Yes/No” and “Folder”.  I have maintained your sequence although I have added “Folder”.

I have named the main macros as “Part1” and “Part2” so there is no confusion with the other macros.  All the other macros are from my library.  They are more complicated than you need but I did not want to spend time coding something simpler.  I suggest you accept these routines do what the comments say and not worry about how.

You have not said if the source of the emails is always the same shared folder. I added the folder column to allow for multiple shared folders.  It means macro “Part2” does not need to ask about the source folder since it gets this information from the workbook although it would need to be told about the destination folder.

You do not say how you create the formulae that sets the value in the “Yes/No” column. I would get macro “Part1” to create them and I have included an example which sets “Yes” or “No” depending on the length of the subject.

In macro “Part1”, I use “For Each FldrSrcNameArr … ” to get details of emails from two folders.  If you have fixed source folders, you can use something similar.  If your requirement is more complicated, you will need to provide more detail.

Macro “Part1” adds new emails below any existing rows.  In macro “Part2”, I clear the rows for emails that are moved and then write the remaining rows back to the worksheet.  I know your macros do not work like this but I wanted to show what is possible.  You can easily delete the redundant code if you do not require it.

I believe you should find it easy to adjust the following code to your requirements. Come back questions if necessary.

```
Option Explicit
  ' Requires references to "Microsoft Excel nn.0 Object Library", "Microsoft Office
  ' nn.0 Object Library" and "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" Value of "nn" depends
  ' on version of Office being used.

  ' Technique for locating desktop from answer by Kyle:
  ' http://stackoverflow.com/a/17551579/973283

  Const ColEmailSender As Long = 1
  Const ColEmailSubject As Long = 2
  Const ColEmailReceived As Long = 3
  Const ColEmailYesNo As Long = 4
  Const ColEmailFolderName As Long = 5
  Const RowEmailDataFirst As Long = 2

Sub Part1()

  Dim ColEmailLast As Long
  Dim FldrSrc As Folder
  Dim FldrSrcName As String
  Dim FldrSrcNameArr As Variant
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem
  Dim ItemsSrc As Items
  Dim Path As String
  Dim RowEmailCrnt As Long
  Dim WbkEmail As Excel.Workbook
  Dim WshtEmail As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

  Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"

  Set xlApp = Application.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  xlApp.Visible = True         ' This slows your macro but helps during debugging
  With xlApp
    Set WbkEmail = .Workbooks.Open(Path & "OE.xlsx")
  End With

  With WbkEmail
    Set WshtEmail = .Worksheets("Emails")
  End With
  Call FindLastRowCol(WshtEmail, RowEmailCrnt, ColEmailLast)

  ' Output first new row under any existing rows.
  RowEmailCrnt = RowEmailCrnt + 1

  For Each FldrSrcNameArr In VBA.Array(VBA.Array("test folders", "Test emails 1"), _
                                       VBA.Array("test folders", "Test emails 2"))

    Set FldrSrc = GetFldrRef(FldrSrcNameArr)
    FldrSrcName = Join(GetFldrNames(FldrSrc), "|")

    Set ItemsSrc = FldrSrc.Items
    ' This shows how to sort the emails by a property should this be helpful.
    ItemsSrc.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"        ' Ascending sort. Add ", False" for descending

    For Each ItemCrnt In ItemsSrc
      With ItemCrnt
        WshtEmail.Range(WshtEmail.Cells(RowEmailCrnt, 1), _
                        WshtEmail.Cells(RowEmailCrnt, 5)).Value = _
               VBA.Array(.SenderEmailAddress, .Subject, .ReceivedTime, _
                         "=IF(MOD(LEN(" & ColCode(ColEmailSubject) & RowEmailCrnt & "),2)=0,""Yes"",""No"")", _
                         FldrSrcName)
      End With
      RowEmailCrnt = RowEmailCrnt + 1
    Next

    Set ItemCrnt = Nothing
    Set ItemsSrc = Nothing
    Set FldrSrc = Nothing

  Next

  WbkEmail.Close SaveChanges:=True

  Set WshtEmail = Nothing
  Set WbkEmail = Nothing
  xlApp.Quit
  Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
Sub Part2()

  Dim ColEmailCrnt As Long
  Dim ColEmailLast As Long
  Dim FldrDest As Folder
  Dim FldrSrc As Folder
  Dim FldrSrcNameCrnt As String
  Dim FldrSrcNamePrev As String
  Dim InxIS As Long
  Dim ItemsSrc As Items
  Dim ItemsToMove As New Collection
  Dim Path As String
  Dim RngSortF As Range
  Dim RngSortR As Range
  Dim RngWsht As Range
  Dim RowEmailCrnt As Long
  Dim RowEmailLast As Long
  Dim WbkEmail As Excel.Workbook
  Dim WshtEmail As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim WshtEmailValues As Variant
  Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

  Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"

  Set xlApp = Application.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  xlApp.Visible = True         ' This slows your macro but helps during debugging
  With xlApp
    Set WbkEmail = .Workbooks.Open(Path & "OE.xlsx")
  End With

  With WbkEmail
    Set WshtEmail = .Worksheets("Emails")
  End With
  Call FindLastRowCol(WshtEmail, RowEmailLast, ColEmailLast)

  With WshtEmail

    Set RngWsht = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowEmailLast, ColEmailLast))
    Set RngSortF = .Range(.Cells(2, ColEmailFolderName), .Cells(RowEmailLast, ColEmailFolderName))
    Set RngSortR = .Range(.Cells(2, ColEmailReceived), .Cells(RowEmailLast, ColEmailReceived))

    ' Ensure rows are sequecnced by Folder name then Received
    ' For each folder, the items are sorted by ReceivedTime.  THis means the two lists
    ' are in the same sequence.
    With .Sort
      .SortFields.Clear
      .SortFields.Add Key:=RngSortF, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                         Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
      .SortFields.Add Key:=RngSortR, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                         Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
      .SetRange RngWsht
      .Header = xlYes
      .MatchCase = False
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .SortMethod = xlPinYin
      .Apply
    End With

    WshtEmailValues = RngWsht.Value

  End With

  FldrSrcNamePrev = ""
  Set FldrDest = GetFldrRef("test folders", "No response")

  For RowEmailCrnt = RowEmailDataFirst To RowEmailLast
    If WshtEmailValues(RowEmailCrnt, ColEmailYesNo) = "Yes" Then
      ' This row identifies an email that is to be moved
      FldrSrcNameCrnt = WshtEmailValues(RowEmailCrnt, ColEmailFolderName)
      If FldrSrcNamePrev <> FldrSrcNameCrnt Then
        ' New source folder
        Set FldrSrc = Nothing
        Set FldrSrc = GetFldrRef(Split(FldrSrcNameCrnt, "|"))
        FldrSrcNamePrev = FldrSrcNameCrnt
        Set ItemsSrc = FldrSrc.Items
        ItemsSrc.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"
        InxIS = 1
      End If
      ' Scan down mail items within sorted folder until reach or are past current email
      Do While InxIS <= ItemsSrc.Count
        If ItemsSrc(InxIS).ReceivedTime >= WshtEmailValues(RowEmailCrnt, ColEmailReceived) Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        InxIS = InxIS + 1
      Loop
      If InxIS <= ItemsSrc.Count Then
        If ItemsSrc(InxIS).ReceivedTime = WshtEmailValues(RowEmailCrnt, ColEmailReceived) And _
           ItemsSrc(InxIS).SenderEmailAddress = WshtEmailValues(RowEmailCrnt, ColEmailSender) And _
           ItemsSrc(InxIS).Subject = WshtEmailValues(RowEmailCrnt, ColEmailSubject) Then
          ' Have found email to be moved
          ' ItemsSrc is what VBA calls a Collection but most languages call a List.
          ' Moving a mail item to another folder removes an item from the Collection and
          ' upsets the index. Better to save a reference to the mail item and move it later.
          ItemsToMove.Add ItemsSrc(InxIS)
          ' Clear row in WshtEmailValues to indicate email moved
          For ColEmailCrnt = 1 To ColEmailLast
            WshtEmailValues(RowEmailCrnt, ColEmailCrnt) = ""
          Next
          InxIS = InxIS + 1
        ' Else  there is no mail item matching email row
        End If
      ' Else  no more emails in folder
      End If
    ' Else email row marled "No"
    End If
  Next

  ' Move mail items marked "Yes"
  Do While ItemsToMove.Count > 0
    ItemsToMove(1).Move FldrDest
    ItemsToMove.Remove 1
  Loop

  ' Upload worksheet values with rows for moved files cleared
  RngWsht.Value = WshtEmailValues

  ' Sort blank lines to bottom
  With WshtEmail
    With .Sort
      .Apply
    End With
  End With

  WbkEmail.Close SaveChanges:=True
  Set WshtEmail = Nothing
  Set WbkEmail = Nothing
  xlApp.Quit
  Set xlApp = Nothing
  'Set ItemCrnt = Nothing
  'Set ItemsSrc = Nothing
  'Set FldrSrc = Nothing

End Sub
' =================== Standard Outlook VBA routines ===================
Function GetFldrNames(ByRef Fldr As Folder) As String()

  ' * Fldr is a folder. It could be a store, the child of a store,
  '   the grandchild of a store or more deeply nested.
  ' * Return the name of that folder as a string array in the sequence:
  '    (0)=StoreName (1)=Level1FolderName (2)=Level2FolderName  ...

  ' 12Oct16  Coded
  ' 20Oct16  Renamed from GetFldrNameStr and amended to return a string array
  '          rather than a string

  Dim FldrCrnt As Folder
  Dim FldrNameCrnt As String
  Dim FldrNames() As String
  Dim FldrNamesRev() As String
  Dim FldrPrnt As Folder
  Dim InxFN As Long
  Dim InxFnR As Long

  Set FldrCrnt = Fldr
  FldrNameCrnt = FldrCrnt.Name
  ReDim FldrNamesRev(0 To 0)
  FldrNamesRev(0) = Fldr.Name
  ' Loop getting parents until FldrCrnt has no parent.
  ' Add names of Fldr and all its parents to FldrName as they are found
  Do While True
    Set FldrPrnt = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FldrPrnt = Nothing   ' Ensure value is Nothing if following statement fails
    Set FldrPrnt = FldrCrnt.Parent
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FldrPrnt Is Nothing Then
      ' FldrCrnt has no parent
      Exit Do
    End If
    ReDim Preserve FldrNamesRev(0 To UBound(FldrNamesRev) + 1)
    FldrNamesRev(UBound(FldrNamesRev)) = FldrPrnt.Name
    Set FldrCrnt = FldrPrnt
  Loop

  ' Copy names to FldrNames in reverse sequence so they end up in the correct sequence
  ReDim FldrNames(0 To UBound(FldrNamesRev))
  InxFN = 0
  For InxFnR = UBound(FldrNamesRev) To 0 Step -1
    FldrNames(InxFN) = FldrNamesRev(InxFnR)
    InxFN = InxFN + 1
  Next

  GetFldrNames = FldrNames

End Function
Function GetFldrRef(ParamArray FolderNames() As Variant) As Folder

  ' FolderNames can be used as a conventional ParamArray: a list of values. Those
  ' Values must all be strings.
  ' Alternatively, its parameter can be a preloaded one-dimensional array of type
  ' Variant or String. If of type Variant, the values must all be strings.
  ' The first, compulsory, entry in FolderNames is the name of a Store.
  ' Each subsequent, optional, entry  in FolderNames is the name of a folder
  ' within the folder identified by the previous names.  Example calls:
  '  1) Set Fldr = GetFolderRef("outlook data file")
  '  2) Set Fldr = GetFolderRef("outlook data file", "Inbox", "Processed")
  '  3) MyArray = Array("outlook data file", "Inbox", "Processed")
  '     Set Fldr = GetFolderRef(MyArray)
  ' Return a reference to the folder identified by the names or Nothing if it
  ' does not exist

  Dim FolderNamesDenested() As Variant
  Dim ErrNum As Long
  Dim FldrChld As Folder
  Dim FldrCrnt As Folder
  Dim InxP As Long

  Call DeNestParamArray(FolderNamesDenested, FolderNames)

  If LBound(FolderNamesDenested) > UBound(FolderNamesDenested) Then
    ' No names specified
    Set GetFolderRef = Nothing
    Exit Function
  End If

  For InxP = 0 To UBound(FolderNamesDenested)
    If VarType(FolderNamesDenested(InxP)) <> vbString Then
      ' Value is not a string
      Debug.Assert False     ' Fatal error
      Set GetFolderRef = Nothing
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

  Set FldrCrnt = Nothing
  On Error Resume Next
  Set FldrCrnt = Session.Folders(FolderNamesDenested(0))
  On Error GoTo 0
  If FldrCrnt Is Nothing Then
    ' Store name not recognised
    Debug.Print FolderNamesDenested(0) & " is not recognised as a store"
    Debug.Assert False     ' Fatal error
    Set GetFldrRef = Nothing
    Exit Function
  End If

  For InxP = 1 To UBound(FolderNamesDenested)
  Set FldrChld = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FldrChld = FldrCrnt.Folders(FolderNamesDenested(InxP))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FldrChld Is Nothing Then
      ' Folder name not recognised
      Debug.Print FolderNamesDenested(InxP) & " is not recognised as a folder within " & _
                  Join(GetFldrNames(FldrCrnt), "->")
      Debug.Assert False    ' Fatal error
      Set GetFldrRef = Nothing
      Exit Function
    End If
    Set FldrCrnt = FldrChld
    Set FldrChld = Nothing
  Next

  Set GetFldrRef = FldrCrnt

End Function
' =================== Standard VBA routines ===================
Sub DeNestParamArray(Denested() As Variant, ParamArray Original() As Variant)

  ' Each time a ParamArray is passed to a sub-routine, it is nested in a one
  ' element Variant array.  This routine finds the bottom level of the nesting and
  ' sets RetnValue to the values in the original parameter array so that other routines
  ' need not be concerned with this complication.

    '   Nov10  Coded
    '  6Aug16  Minor correction to documentation
    '  6Aug16  The previous version did not correctly handle an empty ParamArray.
    ' 15Oct16  replaced call of NumDim by call of NumberOfDimensions
    '          Tested that routine could denest a ParamArray that started as a reloaded
    '          array rather than a list of values in a call.

  Dim Bounds         As Collection
  Dim Inx1           As Long
  Dim Inx2           As Long
  Dim DenestedCrnt() As Variant
  Dim DenestedTemp() As Variant

  DenestedCrnt = Original
  ' Find bottom level of nesting
  Do While True
    If VarType(DenestedCrnt) < vbArray Then
      ' Have found a non-array element so must have reached the bottom level
      Debug.Assert False   ' Should have exited loop at previous level
      Exit Do
    End If
    Call NumberOfDimensions(Bounds, DenestedCrnt)
    ' There is one entry in Bounds per dimension in NestedCrnt
    ' Each entry is an array: Bounds(N)(0) = Lower bound of dimension N
    ' and Bounds(N)(1) = Upper bound of dimenssion N
    If Bounds.Count = 1 Then
      If Bounds(1)(0) > Bounds(1)(1) Then
        ' The original ParamArray was empty
        Denested = DenestedCrnt
        Exit Sub
      ElseIf Bounds(1)(0) = Bounds(1)(1) Then
        ' This is a one element array
        If VarType(DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))) < vbArray Then
          ' But it does not contain an array so the user only specified
          ' one value (a literal or a non-array variable)
          ' This is a valid exit from this loop
            'Debug.Assert False
            Exit Do
        End If
        ' The following sometimes crashed Outlook
        'DenestedCrnt = DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))
        If VarType(DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))) = vbArray + vbString Then
          ' DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))) is an array of strings.
          ' This is the array sought but it must be converted to an array
          ' of variants with lower bound = 0 before it can be returned.
          ReDim Denested(0 To UBound(DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))) - LBound(DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))))
          Inx2 = LBound(DenestedCrnt)
          For Inx1 = 0 To UBound(Denested)
            Denested(Inx1) = DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))(Inx2)
            Inx2 = Inx2 + 1
          Next
          Exit Sub
        End If
        DenestedTemp = DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))
        DenestedCrnt = DenestedTemp
      Else
        ' This is a one-dimensional, non-nested array
        ' This is the usual exit from this loop
        Exit Do
      End If
    Else
      ' This is an array but not a one-dimensional array
      ' There is no code for this situation
      Debug.Assert False
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop

  ' Have found bottom level array.  Save contents in Return array.
  If LBound(DenestedCrnt) <> 0 Then
    ' A ParamArray should have a lower bound of 0.  Assume the ParamArray
    ' was loaded with a 1D array that did not have a lower bound of 0.
    ' Build Denested so it has standard lbound
    ReDim Denested(0 To UBound(DenestedCrnt) - LBound(DenestedCrnt))
    Inx2 = LBound(DenestedCrnt)
    For Inx1 = 0 To UBound(Denested)
      Denested(Inx1) = DenestedCrnt(Inx2)
      Inx2 = Inx2 + 1
    Next
  Else
    Denested = DenestedCrnt
  End If

End Sub
Function NumberOfDimensions(ByRef Bounds As Collection, _
                                   ParamArray Params() As Variant) As Long

  ' Example calls of this routine are:
  '    NumDim = NumberOfDimensions(Bounds, MyArray)
  ' or NumDim = NumberOfDimensions(Bounds, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4:E20"))

  ' * Returns the number of dimensions of Params(LBound(Params)).  Param is a ParamArray.
  '   MyArray, in the example call, is held as the first element of array Params.  That is
  '   it is held as Params(LBound(Params)) or Params(LBdP) where LBdP = LBound(Params).
  ' * If the array to test is a regular array, then, in exit, for each dimension, the lower
  '   and upper bounds are recorded in Bounds. Entries in Bounds are zero-based arrays
  '   with two entries: lower bound and upper bound.
  ' * If the array is a worksheet range, the lower bound values in Bounds are 1 and the
  '   upper bound values are the number of rows (first entry in Bounds) or columns (second
  '   entry in Bounds)
  ' * The collection Bounds is of most value to routines that can be pased an array as
  '   a parameter but does not know if that array is a regular array or a range. The values
  '   returned in Bounds means that whether the test array is a regular array or a range,
  '   its elements can be accessed so:
  '      For InxDim1 = Bounds(0)(0) to Bounds(0)(1)
  '        For InxDim2 = Bounds(1)(0) to Bounds(1)(1)
  '          :  :  :
  '        Next
  '      Next

  ' If there is an official way of determining the number of dimensions, I cannot find it.

  ' This routine tests for dimension 1, 2, 3 and so on until it get a failure.
  ' By trapping that failure it can determine the last test that did not fail.

  ' *  Params() is a ParamArray because it allows the passing of arrays of any type.
  ' *  The array to be tested in not Params but Params(LBound(Params)).
  ' *  The routine does not check for more than one parameter.  If the call was
  '    NumDim(Bounds, MyArray1, MyArray2), it would ignore MyArray2.

  '   Jun10  Coded
  '   Jul10  Documentation added
  ' 13Aug16  Return type changed from Integer
  ' 14Aug16  Upgraded to handle ranges. VarType reports a worksheet range as an
  '          array but LBound and UBound do not recognise a range as an array.
  '          Added Bounds to report bounds of both regular arrays and ranges.
  ' 14Aug16  Renamed from NumDim.
  ' 14Aug16  Switched between different approaches as built up understanding of
  '          bounds of ranges as documented elsewhere in macro.
  ' 15Aug16  Switched back to use of TestArray.

  Dim InxDim As Long
  Dim Lbd As Long
  Dim LBdC As Long
  Dim LBdP As Long
  Dim LBdR As Long
  Dim NumDim As Long
  Dim TestArray As Variant
  'Dim TestResult As Long
  Dim UBdC As Long
  Dim UBdR As Long

  Set Bounds = New Collection

  If VarType(Params(LBound(Params))) < vbArray Then
    ' Variable to test is not an array
    NumberOfDimensions = 0
    Exit Function
  End If

  On Error Resume Next

  LBdP = LBound(Params)

  TestArray = Params(LBdP)

  NumDim = 1
  Do While True
    Lbd = LBound(TestArray, NumDim)
    'Lbd = LBound(Params(LBdP), NumDim)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      If NumDim > 1 Then
        ' Only known reason for failing is because array
        ' does not have NumDim dimensions
        NumberOfDimensions = NumDim - 1
        On Error GoTo 0
        For InxDim = 1 To NumberOfDimensions
          Bounds.Add VBA.Array(LBound(TestArray, InxDim), UBound(TestArray, InxDim))
          'Bounds.Add VBA.Array(LBound(Params(LBdP), InxDim), _
                               UBound(Params(LBdP), InxDim))
        Next
        Exit Function
      Else
        Err.Clear
        Bounds.Add VBA.Array(TestArray.Row, TestArray.Rows.Count - TestArray.Row + 1)
        Bounds.Add VBA.Array(TestArray.Column, TestArray.Columns.Count - TestArray.Column + 1)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
          NumberOfDimensions = 0
          Exit Function
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        NumberOfDimensions = 2
        Exit Function
      End If

    End If
    NumDim = NumDim + 1
  Loop

End Function
' =================== Standard Excel routines ===================
Function ColCode(ByVal ColNum As Long) As String

  ' Convert column number to column code
  ' For example: 1 -> A, 2 -> B, 26 -> Z and 27 -> AA

  Dim PartNum As Long

  '  3Feb12  Adapted to handle three character codes.
  ' 28Oct16  Renamed ColCode to match ColNum.

  If ColNum = 0 Then
    Debug.Assert False
    ColCode = "0"
  Else
    ColCode = ""
    Do While ColNum > 0
      PartNum = (ColNum - 1) Mod 26
      ColCode = Chr(65 + PartNum) & ColCode
      ColNum = (ColNum - PartNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
  End If

End Function
Sub FindLastRowCol(ByRef Wsht As Worksheet, ByRef RowLast As Long, _
                   ByRef ColLast As Long)

  ' Sets RowLast and ColLast to the last row and column with a value
  ' in worksheet Wsht

  ' The motivation for coding this routine was the discovery that Find by
  ' previous row found a cell formatted as Merge and Center but Find by
  ' previous column did not.
  ' I had known the Find would missed merged cells but this was new to me.

  '   Dec16  Coded
  ' 31Dec16  Corrected handling of UsedRange
  ' 15Feb17  SpecialCells was giving a higher row number than Find for
  '          no reason I could determine.  Added code to check for a
  '          value on rows and columns above those returned by Find

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColLastFind As Long
  Dim ColLastOther As Long
  Dim ColLastTemp As Long
  Dim ColLeft As Long
  Dim ColRight As Long
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowIncludesMerged As Boolean
  Dim RowBot As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLastFind As Long
  Dim RowLastOther As Long
  Dim RowLastTemp As Long
  Dim RowTop As Long

  With Wsht

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      RowLastFind = 0
      ColLastFind = 0
    Else
      RowLastFind = Rng.Row
      ColLastFind = Rng.Column
    End If

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If not Rng Is Nothing Then
      If RowLastFind < Rng.Row Then
        RowLastFind = Rng.Row
      End If
      If ColLastFind < Rng.Column Then
        ColLastFind = Rng.Column
      End If
    End If

    Set Rng = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      RowLastOther = 0
      ColLastOther = 0
    Else
      RowLastOther = Rng.Row
      ColLastOther = Rng.Column
    End If

    Set Rng = .UsedRange
    If not Rng Is Nothing Then
      If RowLastOther < Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1 Then
        RowLastOther = Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1
      End If
      If ColLastOther < Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1 Then
        ColLastOther = Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1
      End If
    End If

    If RowLastFind < RowLastOther Then
      ' Higher row found by SpecialCells or UserRange
      Do While RowLastOther > RowLastFind
        ColLastTemp = .Cells(RowLastOther, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If ColLastTemp > 1 Or .Cells(RowLastOther, 1).Value <> "" Then
          ' Row after RowLastFind has value
          RowLastFind = RowLastOther
          Exit Do
        End If
        RowLastOther = RowLastOther - 1
      Loop
    ElseIf RowLastFind > RowLastOther Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ' Is this possible
    End If
    RowLast = RowLastFind

    If ColLastFind < ColLastOther Then
      ' Higher column found by SpecialCells or UserRange
      Do While ColLastOther > ColLastFind
        RowLastTemp = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColLastOther).End(xlUp).Row
        If RowLastTemp > 1 Or .Cells(1, ColLastOther).Value <> "" Then
          Debug.Assert False
          ' Column after ColLastFind has value
          ColLastFind = ColLastOther
          Exit Do
        End If
        ColLastOther = ColLastOther - 1
      Loop
    ElseIf ColLastFind > ColLastOther Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ' Is this possible
    End If
    ColLast = ColLastFind

  End With

  End Sub
```

Comment: so at the point of `Set Fldr = GetFolderRef("outlook data file")` is `"outlook data file" to be replaced by the mailbox name in question?

Comment: For example in my case it would be `Set Fldr = GetFolderRef("sourcefolder", "No Response")` ? if not which part of the code allows me to find the folder ref? I've looked at `GetFldrNames`, firstly that won't run (presumably because it's a function not a subroutine) and secondly it outputs the result to a variable (which I'm also guessing that is referenced further in the process.)

Comment: I tried a run through Part 1, it errored at `Set GetFolderRef = ("outlook data file")` so I added `Dim GetFolderRef As String` and it errors as `object required`

Comment: @JohnMurrey  `GetFldrRef` is a function within the code I supplied. At the top of the function are instructions on its use although I have just notices those instructions use its old name, `GetFolderRef`; sorry.  "outlook data file" is Outlook's name for its default Store.  A Store is a file on disc in which Outlook store's all its information.  I have no access to a shared folder these days but my recollection from my days in a large organisation is that they appeared in my Folder Pane just like all my local and server Stores.  A Store can contain folders in which you can store, ...

Comment: ... for example, mail items. A folder of mail items can hold sub-folders and sub-sub-folders to any depth.  The parameters to a call of `GetFldrRef` start with the name of the Store followed by the name of a folder within that Store followed by the name of a sub-folder and so on down to whatever depth is necessary. If this is not clear, I need to see an image of your Folder Pane so I can be more specific.  You could include an image in your question or you could email it to me.

Comment: OK, I'm familiar with .pst files, I take it the 'store' your referring to will effectively be the .pst file that outlook stores it's data (up until now I only thought local data) and therefor the name of the store will be the name of the.pst file? I understand the parent, child, grandchild relationship hierarchy I'll see if I can get it working this morning. Thanks :)

Comment: it looks like I've got a further with it this time, I've updated the code to reflect the changes I've made. it runs up until `FldrNameCrnt = FldrCrnt.Name` then produces the error: 
Run-time error '91':

Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: I have been stepping through the code to try and debug. I've noticed it gets to Debug.Print  FolderNamesDenested(0) and if I hover over for the value it shows FolderNamesDenested(0) = "test folders". being that I don't have any folders with that name it looks like that needs to be replaced in Part 1() in order for it to work. What would I need to replace it with?

Comment: @JohnMurrey "test folders" in the name of a Store on my system that I used to test my code. You must change my store and folder names for your names. Since I do not know the nature of your shared folders I tried to show what was possible. On line 46 I have `For Each FldrSrcNameArr In ... ` where `...` is an array of arrays. So each loop sets `FldrSrcNameArr` to an array which I use as the parameters for `GetFldrRef`. I have tried to show how you could access two different sub-folders within a shared folder.  Do you need this level of functionality?

Comment: @JohnMurrey If you go to [3.4 Listing the names of every folder within every accessible store]( http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/outlook-vba/8874/introduction-part-3-stores-and-all-their-folders/27632/3-4-listing-the-names-of-every-folder-within-every-accessible-store#t=201703161530007625024), you will find `ListStoresAndAllFolders()`:  This routine will create a file on your desktop containing a list of every store and folder it can reach.  If my explanation above is not enough I suggest you copy this routine to a new Outlook VBA module and run it.  ...

Comment: ...  If you update your question with the section that includes your shared folder and the sub-folder or folders within in it you want to access, I can provide you with just the code you need and not something over complicated that you have to update.

Comment: Apologies Tony, I've had a read through the first 2 guides you put up and with a bit of fiddling, the store macros  and common sense I've debugged part 1 so part 1 is fully up and operational now. Thank you! I'm now looking at part 2 and from a quick skim through I can only see a couple of lines that need the folders added `FldrSrcNamePrev = ` do I need to use `GetFldrRef` there? presumably so.`Set FldrDest = GetFldrRef("` which Input the store and folder. OPart 2 currently errors on `Sub DeNestParamArray(Denested() As Variant, ParamArray Original() As Variant)`

Comment: @JohnMurrey There is no need for you to do anything with `FldrSrcNamePrev`.  Part2 allows for multiple source folder names in the workbook. `FldrSrcNamePrev` is used to detect folder name changes since there is code that is only obeyed when the folder name changes.

Comment: @JohnMurrey What error are you getting with Sub `DeNestParamArray`?

Comment: Hi Tony, the error is as follows "Run-time error'9': Subscript out of range", when I click debug it's stuck at this line of code `ReDim Denested(0 To UBound(DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))) - LBound(DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))))`. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnMurrey  Neither `Part1` not `Part2` call `DeNestParamArray` directly.  It is called by `GetFldrRef` to ensure its parameters are in the format expected.  Please describe the call of `GetFldrRef` that led to this error.

Comment: I've sent you an e-mail, I'm not sure why it errors because `GetFldrRef` as far as I can see from ListStoresAndAllFolders is getting a valid store and folder name.